# Is it possible to delete the Where clause in LookUpRows Function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a function that works correctly for me: `Set @Rows= LookUpRows("ENT.YAK Dev","Flag",1)` I want to update the Where clause to display records when "Flag" equals to "1" and "0" too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you're wanting, you'd need to use the API-based [AMPScript](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/) or [SSJS](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/data_extension_server_side_javascript_functions/) functions, BUT, they're not allowed in emails.  You can only use them in landing pages.

If you want to filter on multiple criteria, I would suggest using a [Query Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) to build Data Extensions rows with a single lookup key.  This Query Activity would need to be executed prior to your send using an [Automation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/) or [Program](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/programs/).

Once you've got your new DE populated, you can certainly use the AMPScript lookup functions (like in your example).

Here are some other examples from my blog: [AMPScript Lookup Examples](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/)